# How do you avoid more than one instance of an Activity when created from widget?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, instance

I would like to start my application\activity when a button is pressed in my widget.

I am using this code:

```
    Intent launchApp = context.getPackageManager()


        Intent launchApp = context.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sexy.code");
        launchApp.setData(Uri.parse(listItemClickIntent
                .toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchApp,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

My problem is in a scenario that my application is already alive in the background so everything looks ok until I close that activity that opened and discover another one behind it. It's like I need to exit the application twice.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: please read android manifest launch mode documentation for activity

Comment: @Jesus Dimrix launch mode is not a best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using launch mode flag:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

You activity should look like:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
```

Comment: its not a best practice,while creating fragment everyone had this problem,reason is savedInstanceState while rotating the mobile it will crate instance again and again,every time you want to check savedInstanceState != null or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`launchApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

From the documentation for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

This flag can also be combined with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), as in:

```
launchApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

You can also use them separately, depending on what your desired behavior is.

Comment: The Nickolai Astashonok answer works great , is there any reason to use your way instead ?

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK works the same as launchMode=singleTask.  It's just a matter of preference if you want to do it in code or in XML.